# Which Dynamics CRM Plugin Message to use for routing emails

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

which CRM message should I use when I want my plugin to fire when an existing email is routed manually to another queue (clicking on the ribbon button "Route"?

Comment: Did you try and test the Route message on Email entity or QueueItem entity (create/update) message..?

Comment: I tried using the Route message on email, but to no avail.